# SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x

O que devo fazer quando essa mensagem de erro aparece: "SyntaxError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"?

Não consigo declarar o else da variável. Segue um print do problema e o código:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
escada = 'Sim'
if escada == 'Sim':
    print('Subir na escada e trocar a lâmpada')
else:
    print('Suba na cadeira')
```

Comment: Copie e cole o texto na sua pergunta em vez de colocar capturas de tela. Em geral, capturas de tela já são ruins por atrapalhar buscas futuras, não serem acessíveis para usuários com dificuldades de visão e tornarem mais difícil que a gente rode o código na nossa máquina para testar, mas no seu caso é ainda pior porque não dá pra saber só de olhar, pois o erro pode estar em algum espaço em branco que não dá pra gente ver.

Comment: Reitero o que falou o @PabloAlmeida, realmente a imagem mais atrapalha do que ajuda. Seu codigo parece estar identado, mas tenha em mente uma coisa, se vc usar 4 espaços (o recomendado) em um trecho use em todo o codigo, a mensagem parece indicar que vc usou niveis de identação diferentes no codigo. Python exige o mesmo nivel em todo o codigo, tente seguir a convenção de 4 espaços.

Comment: Obrigada pessoal, não sabia que era ruim. Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o código.

Answer (score -1):

Erro de indentação, python por não possuir chaves, é uma linguagem sensivel ao declarar condicionais, funções, entre outros. Logo, o jeito correto seria:

```
escada = "Sim"
if (escada):
    print("Subir na escada e trocar as lampadas")
else
    print("Vá pegar as escadas")
```

Comment: Eu tentei fazer dessa forma, mas esse erro continuou aparecendo.

Comment: @Alineat Pela msg vc esta usando níveis de identação diferente no codigo, chque isso.

Comment: @Sidon , é isso que não entendo. Eu não sei pq ele diz que estou usando níveis de identação diferentes, eu deixei tudo certinho. O if e o else fazem parte do primeiro nível e o print faz parte do segundo nível, mas ele continua dando erro.

Comment: O problema pode estar em outra parte do codigo, a msg de erro diz que a parte não identada não "casa" com nenhuma outro nível de identaçao, não procure somente nesse trecho de codigo. Se for um arquivo unico, poste-o completo no [https://repl.it/](https://repl.it/), ou outro serviço equivalente, que a gente testa. :-)

Comment: @Sidon , parece que é algo com o IDLE mesmo. Se eu uso outro editor de código eu consigo escrever sem esses erros.

Comment: Use o [pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) e nunca mais vai querer outra coisa para trabalhar no python. :-)

Comment: O codigo dessa resposta tem erro de sintaxe.

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade temos um erro de sintaxe, este código funciona.

```
escada = "Sim"
if escada:
   print("Subir na escada e trocar as lampadas")
else:
   print("Va pegar as escadas")

>>> 'Subir na escada e trocar as lampadas'
```

Comment: O código original da pergunta está correto (e não tem diferença da sua resposta) , tb funciona!

Comment: Eu sei que está correto, apenas melhorei ele, já que a linguagem me permite escrever de forma mais limpa.
E na verdade se parar para observar o código postado, ele  esqueceu do **:** logo depois do else, por isso que estava dando o erro.